# Overriding bootstrap maxWidth using Javascript and not css

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a .js file containing this:

```
var styles = {
wrap: {
left: 0
, top: 0
, overflow: 'hidden'
, margin: 0
, padding: 0
, height: '100%'
, width: '100%'
, zIndex: -999999
}
, img: {
position: 'absolute'
, display: 'none'
, margin: 0
, padding: 0
, border: 'none'
, width: 'auto'
, height: 'auto'
, maxHeight: 'none'
, maxWidth: 'none'
, zIndex: -999999
}
};
```

And the maxWidth line is being overridden by bootstrap. I want to override bootstrap by effectively making maxWidth !important, but am unsure about the correct syntax in doing so, for example:

```
, maxWidth: 'none !important'
```

Doesn't work. I can solve this problem by adding the rule as important in a stylesheet but am looking for a solution that doesn't require the use of the stylesheet.

Comment: are you adding the style before or after bootstrap? you can check that with the dev tools and take a look at the stack of css rules that are being applied for the particular element.  Also, all styles applied to the element will have precedence over class. Take a look at this article: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Answer (score 0):

Put the js containing those values after the bootstrap files. (Or just to be sure, put it at the end of the page)